# Blank postscript files from plot

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, wxmpl

I have a matplotlib figure inside of a wxmpl panel, and am trying to print it to a Postscript file.  The best I can get is a blank file - by 'blank' I don't mean empty, but rather a .ps file with headers and whatnot but displays as just a blank page.

The code to print is:

```
printer = self.GetPrinter() # wxmpl.FigurePrinter
fig = self.get_figure() # matplotlib.figure.Figure
printData = wx.PrintData(printer.getPrintData())
printer.printFigure(fig, "Plot")
self.printer.setPrintData(printData) # reset print data (avoid segfaults)
```

I took a look into the wxmpl code and found that `OnPrintPage` is never called, so I tried adding a call to that via `wxmpl.FigurePrintout.OnBeginDocument`.  Then `OnPrintPage` gets to this line:

`self.GetDC().DrawBitmap(image.ConvertToBitmap(), wM_Dx, hM_Dx, False)`

and throws an error:

```
wx._core.PyAssertionError
C++ assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed in ../src/generic/dcpsg.cpp(2238): invalid postscript dc
```

Google led me to [this email string](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Fwd-wxPostscriptDC-problems-td2364034.html), and accordingly I tried replacing the above line with:

```
dc = self.GetDC()
dc.StartDoc("printing stuff")
dc.StartPage()
dc.BeginDrawing()
dc.DrawBitmap(image.ConvertToBitmap(), wM_Dx, hM_Dx, False)
dc.EndDrawing()
dc.EndPage()
dc.EndDoc()
```

That got rid of the error -- but after all that it's still just printing blank files as before.

Another note, simply saving the plot as Postscript works fine - it uses a different backend (FigureCanvasWxAgg instead of RendererAgg - so maybe the problem is in matplotlib instead of wxmpl/wxPython?).  However, I need to print this to an actual printer as well, so special-casing for .ps files isn't really a viable solution.

Running Linux
wxmpl version 1.2.9
wxPython version 2.6.4.0
matplotlib version 0.84 (yes, I know it's horribly outdated, but that's what I have to work with for now)

Comment: Update - I had put the wrong function signature for OnBeginDocument, so it wasn't getting called.  I fixed that so that OnPrintPage was called, and it did print correctly (although the output files seem way too big - but that's a different problem).  The question still remains of why OnPrintPage isn't being called normally, however.  Any info would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that wxmpl had no call to `HasPage` --  the entirety of the changes above didn't matter, after all.  Adding in this code in class `FigurePrintout` fixed the issue with not printing:

```
def HasPage(self, page):
    return page <= 1
```

Yep... two lines.  Based on the documentation for the wxPython printing framework, the default is `return page == 1`, but wxmpl returns 0 as the first page in it's override of `GetPageInfo`.  So the printer didn't think it had a page to print.